# What is the difference between SerializeToZeroCopyStream and SerializeToOstream when using std::cout?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there any efficiency difference between

```
my_msg.SerializeToOstream(&std::cout);
```

and

```
google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream zcos(&std::cout);
my_msg.SerializeToZeroCopyStream(&zcos);
```

?

Google documentation doesn't say much:

- [Message::SerializeToOstream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.SerializeToOstream.details)
- [MessageLite::SerializeToZeroCopyStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.SerializeToZeroCopyStream.details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/ed4321d1cb33199984118d801956822842771e7e/src/google/protobuf/message.cc). Basically, they are the same.

```
bool Message::SerializeToOstream(std::ostream* output) const {
  {
    io::OstreamOutputStream zero_copy_output(output);
    if (!SerializeToZeroCopyStream(&zero_copy_output)) return false;
  }
  return output->good();
}
```